# Expect Script - bash script file not found

Tags: bash, macintosh, expect

My expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#I tried replacing sh - with bash -s still no positive results
spawn ssh xxxx@yyyy "sh -" < test.sh
expect "password: "
send "zzzzz\r"
expect "$ "
```

This command works well if executed in the terminal

```
ssh xxxx@yyyy "sh -" < test.sh
```

But if I execute it via `expect` script; it fails.

This is the output if I execute it via the expect script. May I know where I am going wrong

```
bash: test.sh: No such file or directory
```

P.S : Yes, the file exists and the credentials are right.

Comment: cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120500/expect-script-bash-script-file-not-found

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes I thought I posted in the `wrong forum` and posted it here, but couldn't unfortunately delete it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the redirection with `<` is being done locally when you run ssh on its own (by the shell you are typing into), but being done on the remote machine when you run from `expect`, because `spawn` simply copies the arguments you provide, so the `<` is passed to the remote as part of the ssh command. It is as if you typed `'ssh' 'xxxx@yyyy' "sh -" '<' 'test.sh'` to the shell, which similarly will not work.

You need to add an intermediate shell command to get the redirection parsed before the ssh. Use for example,

```
spawn sh -c "ssh xxxx@yyyy sh - < test.sh"
```